# two mathcal families in the same document

Tags: fonts, math-mode, unicode-math

Is it possible to use two math fonts from the calligraphy families in the same document?
Something like `$\mathcal{P}$` from Zapfino and `$\mathcal{T}$` from XITS math?

Comment: If my guess is right that you are using `unicode-math`, please add that in your question and as a tag.

Comment: @Caramdir: from the name of the fonts, it is a good guess but I am also interested in non xelatex answers. I do not want to limit my question to the use of `unicode-math` even though that I would be my final choice. Thanks

Comment: The answer is completely different depending on whether you use `unicode-math` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `unicode-math` (which I assume you are using), you can remap a range of characters to a different font:

```
\setmathfont[range="1D4AB]{Zapfino}
```

(where `"1D4AB` is the unicode slot for the character that should be remapped (see the `unicode-math` manual for the syntax when you want to remap multiple characters)).

The problem is that Zapfino probably doesn't contain the `U+1D4AB MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL P` character. Hence you have to remap that character to `U+0050 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P` first. I don't know if unicode-math has an interface to do that manually (Will should be able to tell). But it does that automatically if you remap a whole range of characters, like

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr]{Zapfino}
```

(Note that remapping `\mathscr` doesn't change `\mathcal` even though by default both display the same character.)

The height of Zapfino probably doesn't match the height of XITS Math. So you have to rescale it:

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Zapfino}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also see a more problematic configuration if I need '\mathcal{P}' from Zapfino as well as '\mathcal{P}' from XITS math.

Comment: @pluton: with the solution above, one is `\mathscr{P}` the other `\mathcal{P}`.

Comment: ok, what about three P?

Comment: @pluton: then you should rethink your notation... (If you tag the question `unicode-math`, you have a better chance that Will Robertson (the author of `unicode-math`) sees it.)

Answer (score 5):

It's possible. This is what `mathrsfs` or `eucal` package does. Let's take have a look at `mathrsfs` package:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{rsfs}{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscr}{rsfs}
```

This shows how to declare a math symbol font and the font command. The first line declares that math font family `rsfs` is `{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}` in NFSS. And the second line give it a command \mathscr. It may be a bit more clear if we use a different math family name other than `rsfs`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathscript}{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscr}{mathscript}
```

or even simpler (waht it should be, I think):

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}
```

Please refer to `fntguide` for datails.

Warning: TeX allows 16 math font family only in a document. (It's too bad....) If you need more, you will have to use text mode to simulate a fake math font family. For example:

```
\newcommand*\mathscr[1]{\text{\usefont{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}#1}}
```

It works differently from math fonts, but may be useful if you have to use a lot of different typefaces of math alphabets.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice the need of Unicode math fonts. What I said is all about traditional method. Although the traditional method can also be used in XeTeX (like Latin Modern), but `unicode-math` is more comfortable as @Caramdir say.

Comment: I just added a comment saying that your answer was of interest to me too.